# How to connect Swift to a postgresql database hosted on Google Cloud

Tags: swift, xcode, postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I'm new to working with back-end, but have been running into issues trying to get my iOS app to connect to my **PostgreSQL DB**.

I have developed an app with Swift which is a game that I want to run locally on iOS devices. I have a PostgreSQL DB set up in **Google Cloud Platform** but I cannot figure out how to get the Swift app to connect to my PostgreSQL DB.

I've read some about using Vapor or Perfect to run the application using Googles App Engine but I'm not sure that is what I want to do since I want the app to run locally but there are a few aspects of my app that I need a global database for.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction of how I need to connect my Swift application with Google Cloud's PostgreSQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I connect an iOS app to Google Cloud SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507547/how-do-i-connect-an-ios-app-to-google-cloud-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty much very similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507547/how-do-i-connect-an-ios-app-to-google-cloud-sql).

In short, the correct answer is you shouldn't connect your client side application directly to the database. Instead, you should build a service that can connect to the database, and act as a service between your application. This helps prevent any unauthorized queries to your database and provides better performance. If you wanted to do this on GCP, you could look into something like [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) or [Google Cloud App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) to act as a service.

An alternative would be to use a "Database-as-a-Service" like [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/). This is a scalable, pay-as-you-go service with great mobile support.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sure you need a server, ruby on rails to connect to your Postgres database.

The server will facilitate data back and forth from the Google cloud Postgressql